# How to Run Phantomjs on Linux Webserver

Tags: javascript, php, linux, wordpress, phantomjs

I am trying to upload the executable file for Phantomjs onto my web server. Currently, wordpress is installed on this server, so calling phantom will be done mainly through the use of `php` functions. The server is running Linux x86_64, which is the same repository of Phantom I have downloaded. In one of my wordpress template files I try to call phantom and attempt to run a script, but nothing is echoed. I know the javascript is right because it was one of the examples provided. Also, the Phantomjs file has adequate permissions to run. So no issues there. Here is all of the code I am trying to use to get this to work correctly.

```
<?php 
/* 
Template Name: Home Template
Description: Page template to show home page content.
*/

//phantom/phantomjs-directory/bin/phantomjs
//phantom/phantomjs-directory/examples/version.js

get_header(); 
?>
<?php 
echo exec('phantom/phantomjs-directory/bin/phantomjs phantom/phantomjs-directory/examples/version.js');
?>
```

The script being called is located one directory back in `examples/` instead of `bin/` and can be found below:

```
"use strict";
console.log('using PhantomJS version ' +
phantom.version.major + '.' +
phantom.version.minor + '.' +
phantom.version.patch);
phantom.exit();
```

Nothing at all is being logged or echoed. Why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple of mistakes with this one. The golden code that did this for me was only this:

```
echo exec('/home/mainshee/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/phantom/phantomjs-directory/bin/phantomjs /home/mainshee/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/phantom/phantomjs-directory/examples/version.js');
```

The major mistake I made was that the paths were not EXACT. You would think that only including the path from he location you were already at would be adequate, but I found they want the ENTIRE path. Start to finish. I also made sure that every file I was trying to execute had `0755` permissions. The last precaution I took was to use `scp` to upload the phantomjs file folder rather than the traditional method. This was done to avoid any corruptions (although I am not sure if it made any difference in the end). Hope this helps somebody else!

Answer (score 1):

Try it with echo and backticks.

```
echo `/phantom/phantomjs myscript.js`;
```

Comment: Nothing is echoed using this method

Comment: what happens when you run that from the shell? Also, make sure the .js is in `pwd`

Comment: Running `bin/phantomjs examples/hello.js` outputs a perfect result. But nothing at all comes from echoing from within a php file.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is

```
exec('/phantom/phantomjs myscript.js', $response);
echo implode("<br>", $response);
```

Anyway you should first check that script works by logging in to server via SSH and trying to run the script manually. PhantomJS binary could mismatch server processor architecture (x64 vs x86).

Also mind the path to the binary and the script, the easiest way is to use absolute paths.

Comment: I am sure that the version of Phantomjs I have on my server is compatible with the server processor architecture. I verified the architecture was x86_64 before installing Phantomjs x86_64 from the website. The script I am using is one of their examples. When I use your code above the only piece that is echoed is "Array". The main concern I have is that within the script shown above no messages are logged to the console. Which makes me believe the script isn't really running, and it is just echoing a default response. Your thoughts?

Comment: My bad, the $response is indeed array, so see updated answer on how to view it.

Comment: The script runs perfectly through `SSH`, but nothing at all happens when I adjust the code to your suggestion above.

Comment: The `$response` array is empty then? Try `exec('/phantom/phantomjs myscript.js', $response, $return_var);` What is `$return_var` ?